# What is a right way to deal with tests, temporary files and version control

Tags: ruby, git, testing, version-control

I use Ruby for writing a code, test it with Cucumber and Rspec and control versions with Git. But here are some unclear things for me. E.g. temporary files, created by tests. I don't want to track their changes with every commit.
So, what way I should use for that:

1. Locate temporary files inside project folder and use some Git tricks for ignoring changes. `gitignore` is not useful, because I need some files to be in the place, when tests are started.
2. Locate temporary files in the `/tmp`. It gives some unclear for test environment, though.
3. Any other ways deal with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The files required when the tests start should be in source control. Ideally you want temp files created by tests to be in one directory so you can ignore the whole directory. If that's not possible then add each file to the .gitignore file. Really, outside of test results, your specs should clean up after themselves, which should include deleting temp files created during testing.

Comment: Ok, I understand what my mistake was: mix "test" and "temp" files. "Test" files I mean files required for running tests and describing predefined system state, which should be tracked. "Temp" files are files created and modified by tests, not necessary for start tests and should not be tracked. Now I put them into separate directories and simply `gitignore` all files inside "temp" folder.

Answer (score 1):

> `gitignore` is not useful,...

[`gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) *should* be useful here:

- either you can limit those temporary files to a dedicated folder within the repo, and you can ignore that all folder;
- or you can identify those temporary files by their extension or naming convention, and you can ignore them by a name pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has facilities for [creating temp files and directories and cleaning them up for you](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html), use that.  It will pick the correct location for temp files for the current environment, probably well outside your repository, and you never have to worry about them again.  While the rule of thumb for tests is to not write files outside your source directory, using a global temp directory is acceptable and reliable.

Otherwise, create a temp directory in your project (possibly inside your test directory) and put all your temp files there.  Set `.gitignore` to ignore that directory.  This has the *slight* advantage of keeping your test artifacts entirely inside your source directory, and you can find them easier for debugging purposes.  You should still use Ruby's Tempfile class to manage them, just tell it to use your temp directory, to handle cleanup and to ensure your temp names are unique to allow parallel testing.

I would recommend just using whatever `Tempfile.new` spits out.  Remembering to set the special test temp directory is one more moving part you don't need.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about Ruby Tempfile, but it is not acceptable in my case, because these temp files have debugging worth. I think it is not have to be so and I should create some logger for my tests, but now I am at this point.